# How to delete the contents of a file in c#?

Tags: c#, delete-file

I'm trying to delete the contents that are inside my file. But when i choose 3 from the menu it deletes my file from the folder not from the file. Can you help me with it please? I'm working on it since yesterday.

Thank you.

```
{
    class test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            movie[] arr = new movie[1];

            bool exit = false;
            while (exit == false)
            {
                menu();
                string choice = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case "1":
                        add(ref arr);


                        break;
                    case "2":
                         saveData(ref arr);

                        break;



                    case "3":
                         deleteData(ref arr);
                      break;


                    case "4":
                        exit = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        // adding data 

        public static void add(ref movie[] arr)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("movie.txt");
            writer.WriteLine(arr.Length + 1);
            // creat new object
            movie temp = new movie();
            // collect data fromuser
            Console.WriteLine("enter title");
            temp.Title = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("enter director");
            temp.Director = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("enter year");
            temp.Year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            // write the new data to text file

            writer.WriteLine(temp.Title);
            writer.WriteLine(temp.Director);
            writer.WriteLine(temp.Year);
            writer.Close();
            // 
        }

        // save data 
        public static void saveData(ref movie[] arr)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("movie.txt");

            int size = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
            arr = new movie[size];
            for (int index = 0; index < arr.Length; index++)
            {
                arr[index] = new movie();
                arr[index].Title = reader.ReadLine();
                arr[index].Director = reader.ReadLine();
                arr[index].Year = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }




         public static void deleteData(ref movie[] arr)
        {


           if(File.Exists("movie.txt"))
                 {
                    File.Delete("movie.txt");
                  }
            else
                 {
                          ;//donothing
                  }
         }

        // menu

        private static void menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("plz chosse one of the following options to continue ");

            Console.WriteLine("1: Add Movie");
            Console.WriteLine("2: Save data");
            Console.WriteLine("3: delete Movie");
            Console.WriteLine("4: Exit");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: debugger. debugger. debugger.

Comment: it does not showing me anything .but thnx for taking ur time and answering my question :)

Comment: If the debugger is not showing anything then you forgot to start your program. Start the program with the debugger, use breakpoints, and step through your code step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the `File.Delete` method of `System.IO` will delete the file from the directory if it exist in the directory, To keep the file and have to delete its contents means You have to use [`File.WriteAllText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> which will Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and
>   then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is
>   overwritten.

```
 string path="path to your file"; // Let it be "movie.txt"
 File.WriteAllText(path, "");
```

*Answer for the second question from the comment:*

If you need to add something(content) to an existing file then you have to use the [`File.AppendAllText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx) Method,

> Which will Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and
>   then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates
>   a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

In this case the snippet should be like this :

```
 File.AppendAllText(path, "Some content to append");
```

Comment: workssss tnx man u r the best

Comment: Cool.... Happy to help you

Comment: one more question

Comment: The question is not clear, you have to be more specific

Comment: lets say i entered 3 movies name and i chose 2 from the menu which it should save the 3 movies name in the file .But when i entered 3 movies name and  it saves the last one only .How i can fix that ?

Comment: There you are, you have to use `AppendAllText` for this time, see the updates in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a line

```
File.Create("movie.txt");
```

below

```
File.Delete("movie.txt");
```

It may not work as you liked it to, but it does the same job, isn't it?

Comment: but that will create a file no?

Comment: i want just delete everything inside the file when im choosing 3 from the menu

Comment: Just add the line and try it yourself. :-)

Comment: it is working bro but when i go to open the file a windows pop up saying  the process cannot access the file bcz it is being used by another process.